# How to modify pivot to Excel form using openpyxl

Tags: excel, openpyxl

***I have a pivot like below***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['banana',1, 'sheep', 2, 'mon', 3], ['apple', 10, 'lion', 20,'son', 30], ['mango',100,'tiger', 200,'father', 300], 
                   ['melon',1000,np.nan,np.nan,'daugter',3000]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((("fruit", "topic"), ("fruit", "qty"), ("animal", "topic"), ("animal", "qty"),("family", "topic"), ("family", "qty")))

df
```

[image]

```
df.to_excel('c:/to_exel.xlsx')
```

[image]

**and I want to change the excel form like below by using openpyxl**

***in detail,***

[image]

***To be more specific, line up regardless of the column,
just excel form cannot exceed the 9th row, and if it does, it moves sideways.***

***Openpyxl professionals, please help***

Comment: Where is your code writing to Excel (where the data is moved across the columns at row 9)?